VS Code search *all* filenames (even `.gitignore`'d filenames)
In VS Code, I sometimes want to search all filenames, including .gitignore'd filenames. Is there a "force" search version of ctrl-p (which searches filenames) that won't exclude the ignored files?
To be clear, I am not looking for ways to always search all filenames (as given in this other SO question) nor am I looking for a way to search the contents of all files.
Most of the time I want to exclude the ignored filenames from my search, but every now and again I want to search all filenames in the codebase. So I want a regular mode and a "really-search-everything" mode. I do not want to have to go digging around in the settings every time, I just want ctrl-p for regular filename search and ctrl-something-else for all-files file search.
More than happy to add an extension if this is not available in default vs code.

You can switch search with / without .gitignored files in User settings / Features / Explorer / Exclude Git Ignore (type >User into Search bar and select Open User Settings, then write gitignore into Search settings bar).
To use a shortcut you may define your own with help of VS Code extension like Toggle. You just need add following code into your keybindings.json:
{
    "key": "f4",
    "command": "toggle",
    "when": "editorFocus",
    "args": {
    "id": "search.useIgnoreFiles",
    "value": [
        {
            "search.useIgnoreFiles": true
        },
        {
            "search.useIgnoreFiles": false
        }
    ]
}

By pressing F4 key (you will probably define your own shortcut) you are able to on/off Use Ignore Files from the opened editor.
Note: to open keybindings.json just open Keyboard Shortcut settings (by pressing Ctrl+K+S) and click on icon Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) upper right side.
